# What's "Relative Error" in a neural network model?

Tags: spss, neural-networks, error

I'm using SPSS for building a neural network model. In the model summary there is a measure called "Relative Error". What's the formula for it? Is it related to sum of squares error?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/20.0/en/client/Manuals/IBM_SPSS_Neural_Network.pdf):

> The relative error for each scale-dependent variable is the ratio of
>   the sum-of-squares error for the dependent variable to the
>   sum-of-squares error for the “null” model, in which the mean value of
>   the dependent variable is used as the predicted value for each case